# Multi Talented Individual

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

> With the help of some of my friends, I can do the following:
>
> - break things apart into pieces (verb)
> - stop people from arguing with one another (noun)
> - make some really strong alcohol (name)
> - make someone feel happier (verb)
> - tell others my thoughts (noun)

what can I do by myself?

Edit:

> In case it isn't clear, my friends are letters.

Edit/hint:

> I am three letters long and will be found in the beginning of some of the words and in the middle of some of the words. Hopefully this condition is enough to make the solution unique/somewhat unique.

Edit:

> I have added the type of word (noun, adjective, verb...) that each clue refers to. Hopefully this narrows the search space down a little.

Edit:

> I see some good answers, but (name) refers to a proper noun(a brand) rather than an object/process.

Hint:

> Interestingly, while none of the proposed solutions seem to perfectly match all the clues, some of answers I had in mind can be found scattered throughout the proposed solutions.

Comment: Oh man I so wanted to answer 'diss' because of disperse, distill and discuss but that is most definitely a prefix on its own. Good puzzle! I really like it!

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

> I think it's a word that has a meaning by itself, but if you add different prefixes/suffixes/infixes, then it will create a word that has a meaning connected to the given hints. I am yet to figure out the word and the letters.

**EDIT**

The answer is:

> ion - I can be charged positively and negatively

break things apart into pieces

> explosion

stop people from arguing with one another

> explanation/conversation/mediation

make some really strong alcohol

> distillation

make someone feel happier

> consolation

tell others my thoughts

> communication

Comment: It feels like the friends are doing all the work here. Usually (I think) it's a tacit assumption in this sort of question that the additions are small.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you explain? I am not even sure if this is the right answer (although I am quite positive I got it right).

Comment: Consider the following answer: "You are the empty string. By adding the letters DISMANTLE we get something that means to break apart into pieces", etc. Obviously that wouldn't be a good answer! Your proposed answer is a common suffix that can be attached to a very wide variety of verbs, and feels to me a little like the "empty string" answer.

Comment: Now I understand. It's still very much possible that it's not the right answer. However, it fits, so it's worth a try :-)

Answer (score 6):

By yourself you can roll around. You are a

> pea!

With your friends you can

> [**pea**rl barley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl_barley) to remove its outer layer,
> ap**pea**se people in an argument by acting as a **pea**cemaker,
> brew up some [Absolut **Pea**rs](https://www.absolut.com/en/products/absolut-pears/),
> ap**pea**l to a person's sensibilities and
> be a s**pea**ker to an audience.

Answer (score 4):

You can

> fool people

because you are

> a con.

break things apart into pieces (verb)

> deCONstruct

stop people from arguing with one another (noun)

> CONcilliate

make some really strong alcohol (name)

> CONdense or CONcentrate

make someone feel happier (verb)

> CONsole

tell others my thoughts (noun)

> CONversation

Answer (score 2):

***UPDATED ANSWER:***

Friend #1

> break things apart into pieces (verb)
> sha**TTE**r (verb) to break at once into pieces or to break suddenly and violently into pieces.

Friend #2

> stop people from arguing with one another (noun)
> rebu**TTE**r (noun) a debater who refutes or disproves by offering contrary evidence or argument.

Friend #3

> make some really strong alcohol (name)
>  [Bi**TTE**rs](https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/345/bitters) 28%–45%

Friend #4

> make someone feel happier (verb)
> pa**TTE**d (verb) To stroke lightly as a gesture of affection, to praise, congratulate or encourage.

Friend #5

> tell others my thoughts (noun)
> le**TTE**r (noun) A written, typed, or printed communication, especially one sent in an envelope by mail or messenger. Used to convey something which are usually thought.

You are an

> acronym

and can:

> *Tell the* **T*ime* T*o* E*at***